# Number Format does not work in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, asp.net-core, dataformat

I try to allow decimals in my application (ASP.NET Core running on .Net 4.5.2 Full Framework in Azure). The application is configured to only use de-DE culture in `Startup.cs` with a custom `DateTime` format:

```
var dtf = new DateTimeFormatInfo
{
    ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy",
    LongDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm",
    ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm",
    LongTimePattern = "HH:mm"
};

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        //new CultureInfo("en-US") { DateTimeFormat = dtf },
        //new CultureInfo("en") { DateTimeFormat = dtf },
        new CultureInfo("de-DE") { DateTimeFormat = dtf },
        new CultureInfo("de") { DateTimeFormat = dtf }
        //new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        //new CultureInfo("en"),
        //new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
        //new CultureInfo("de")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "de-DE", uiCulture: "de-DE");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
```

My model looks like this, I also tried to use `{0:#.###}` which also did not work as well as changing the type to `decimal?`.

```
[Display(Name = "ContainerWeight", ResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:N3}")]
public float? Weight { get; set; }
```

If I Submit my form, I get an error with JavaScript validation if I use e.g. `111,222` on my machine which is an en-US Windows machine and I get a model error in my Controller if I use `111.222`. On a german machine it's exactly the opposite as it seems (I asked someone to check that for me). This is the part of the View:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <label asp-for="Weight" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input asp-for="Weight" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Weight" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I had similar trouble getting the `DateTime` format to work but figured it out, this one seems to hard for me.

Answer (score 7):

As per documentation you have to use localization middleware to set current request culture. You have to do that in the `Configure` method, not in the `ConfigureService` one.

I did following thing in `Configure` method.

```
var dtf = new DateTimeFormatInfo
{
    ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy",
    LongDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm",
    ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm",
    LongTimePattern = "HH:mm"
};

var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    //new CultureInfo("en-US") { DateTimeFormat = dtf },
    //new CultureInfo("en") { DateTimeFormat = dtf },
    new CultureInfo("de-DE") { DateTimeFormat = dtf },
    new CultureInfo("de") { DateTimeFormat = dtf }
    //new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    //new CultureInfo("en"),
    //new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
    //new CultureInfo("de")
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de-DE"),
    // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    // UI strings that we have localized.
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

After that I created sample model.

```
public class TestModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:N3}")]
    public float? Weight { get; set; }
}
```

And Pass Value `111,112` from UI and it successfully validated in UI as well at controller level as well.